# Unslider CSS: Images are not contained on the page?

Tags: css

The live site is on [this website](http://cbbp.github.io), I was not able to reproduce on a Fiddle, and am trying to still make one.

However, notice that on the Unslider, **on the left corner** the images leak into one another, and I am unsure how to curb this behaviour.

Any input would be great.

Comment: My guess is that you have a margin-left somewhere..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css change the padding on the parent `<ul>` to `0`.

```
.banner ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
}
```